# Footer Total Gridview TextChangedEvent

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Textbox with in the Gridview Control.when i enter amount on Textbox i have to show on Gridview Footer.

i have tried this,

```
static float total=0;

 protected void txtintroId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;

    GridViewRow grid = ((GridViewRow)txt.Parent.Parent.Parent);

    TextBox txt1= (TextBox)txt.FindControl("txtbox");
     total=float.parse(txt1.Text);
    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

its working, but The problem is when Change the Same Textbox value again and again.the textbox value Add with Total.
how do i Solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of `txt.Parent.Parent.Parent` use `txt.NamingContainer`.
2. Second, don't use a static field in ASP.NET. This is shared across **all** requests. Instead use `ViewState`/`Session`/`Hiddenfield` to persist a value across postbacks.
3. if you don't want that it gets summed then don't persist it acoss postbacks, just recalculate it:

---

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
float value = float.Parse(txt.Text);
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) txt.NamingContainer;
GridView gridView = (GridView) row.NamingContainer;
float total = gridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Sum(row => float.Parse(((TextBox) row.FindControl("txtbox")).Text));
```

If you can't use LINQ or the TextBoxes can be empty or contain other invalid formats use a plain loop:

```
float total = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in gridView.Rows)
{
    txt = (TextBox) gridViewRow.FindControl("txtbox");
    float rowValue = 0;
    if (float.TryParse(txt.Text.Trim(), out rowValue))
        total += rowValue;
}
```

Comment: differnce Between "txt.Parent.Parent.Parent" and  "txt.NamingContainer."

Comment: @King_Fisher: the difference is that `NamingContainer` works always, even if you change the structure in future. So it's more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: @King_Fisher: note that i've edited the answer since there was a bug(`txt.FindControl` instead of `row.FindControl`).

Comment: its throw exception  here "
    .Sum(r => float.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtbox")).Text));"

Comment: @King_Fisher: does this exception have a name and a text? That LINQ query is similar to a loop which increases a `float`-value for every `GridViewRow`. So can you use LINQ, have you added `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Comment: i did that already ,its says "Input string Was not Correct Format"

Comment: if i used your previous answer"txt.FindControl" its working but not Correct amount

Comment: @King_Fisher: so are some textboxes empty? You could change the code in the `Sum`, but maybe it's easier to use a simple loop(`foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows) ...`). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: you  are right. i have 10 Textbox on Gridview.i want to calculate which is filled only.

Comment: Thanks Tim.its working fine.i was struggling 2 hours :)

Comment: what's meaning of this line  " if (float.TryParse(txt.Text.Trim(), out rowValue))"

Comment: @King_Fisher: that's using [`float.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns `true` if the string could be parsed to `float` and `false` otherwise. It also needs an `out`-parameter which is the value that is returned from the method in case it could be parsed. `txt.Text.Trim()` just removes leading and trailing spaces in case the user typed something like `" 123  "`(note the empty spaces before and behind 123). This sometimes happens if the user copy-pastes values.